# How do I completely erase my HDDs for Linux

Tags: drive

I'm trying to erase both my HDDs for Linux usage just like they were with the initial Windows 10 install. I thought I was doing so when I used the Ubuntu option of erasing my SSD, but it looks like it's still trying to use the original dual boot partition for it. This is my first foray into Linux so I'm a complete beginner, but here's my screenshot of what I'm seeing:

[Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeXbs.jpg)

The 97 GB Computer is the partition I originally created. It's off the 3 TB HDD, not the SSD.

Comment: Add the result of `df -h` to your question and then run 'sudo gparted' and confirm all your drives and partitions. Don't create or format anything yet.

Comment: You cannot edit or change partitions that are *mounted*.

Comment: ...also, are you using 2 or 3 drives? you mention 2 HDDs and an SSD... but I only see 2 drives in your picture... Using gnome-disks, or df -h, or even fdisk -l offers a better picture... and like Nmath mentioned, it's hard to determine what it is you exactly want to do.. i posted an answer to completely erase your disks or just master boot record, but deleted it when I saw your picture then reread your question...

Answer (score 0):

Boot your computer off your Ubuntu installer USB/DVD. When prompted to select between "Try Ubuntu" or "Install Ubuntu", select "Try Ubuntu".
Go to the search (the one that opens when you press the Windows key) and type in Disks. Open Disks, and click on the first drive you want to erase. Select the button with 3 dots on it in around the top right corner. Select "Format Disk". If your computer has UEFI firmware instead of a BIOS (most computers that come with Windows 8 or later have UEFI) then select GPT from the drop down list and click format; if your computer has a legacy BIOS instead, then format it as MBR/DOS. Then, reinstall Ubuntu after you've formatted the drives that you want to erase. Windows should be gone now - post back if it isn't gone. This might not work, as this answer is based on my personal experience. If it doesn't work, then remember to post back!

Comment: Wait, don't do this yet - follow darth_epoxy's instructions first, then do this. And is the 97GB partition the one with Ubuntu on it, and the 3TB HDD the one with Windows on it? If so, then wipe the 3TB HDD, and if the Ubuntu install isn't on the HDD, then don't reinstall.

Comment: The Ubuntu install was a partition on the 3 TB drive as I originally planned on dual boot. I couldn't erase that drive since it was the one my only functioning OS was on. I used the above comment's instructions prior to seeing your post. Ubuntu recognizes both drives for installation so I'm not worried about them not being there.